# How to check if a C# type was statically constructed

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm writing a diagnostic tool to examine all domain types across all loaded assemblies. As a part of diagnostics I need to check static fields of the types. So, there is a problem when some class was never accessed before and I request a value of some of its static fields using reflection then static construction of the class happens. I would like to check in some way if the class was statically constructed already and if not to skip it.

Comment: You can easily check which assemblies have already been loaded. But checking which types have been instantiated, which not, especially when it comes to static instantiation? Whoa, probably have to analyze to contents of the managed heap. There' some tools to do so, never used them
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension

Comment: Also, the implementation of type initialization changed between .NET versions (see e.g. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/).

Comment: Following the trail of `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor` there is this check: [`if (pMT->IsClassInited())`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ec3e0b276b159ab24946f17f2b89d00862488a6a/src/coreclr/vm/reflectioninvocation.cpp#L1594). I could not find a place where this method is exposed to the managed context, but maybe there is a way to call this method anyway.